# Bootstrap navbar dropdown not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, dropdown

I'm having an issue where a dropdown menu in my navbar works on a desktop, but doesn't expand in mobile.

Here is the live site: http://launchsummer.org/

If you shrink the page to mobile-sized, you'll see that the "launch summer" dropdown does not expand.

Here is the code for the navbar:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<!-- Note: navbar-default and navbar-inverse are both supported with this theme. -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-expanded">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="[[~1]]">
                <img src="assets/logo-nav@2x.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="[[~1]]">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="[[~3]]">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Launch Summer <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="[[~4]]"><font color="#080A21">Program Details</font></a></li>
                        <li><a href="[[~5]]"><font color="#080A21">FAQ</font></a></li>
                        <li><a href="[[~6]]"><font color="#080A21">Launch Alumni</font></a></li>
                        <li><a href="[[~2]]"><font color="#080A21">Past Companies</font></a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="https://launch.fluidreview.com/" target="_blank"><font color="#080A21">Apply!</font></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.edx.org/course/becoming-entrepreneur-mitx-launch-x" target="_blank">LaunchX</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.mitlaunchclubs.com" target="_blank">Launch Clubs</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://launchsummer.wordpress.com/" target="_blank">Blog</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your vitality.js, at line 23 to 26, you have this function :

```
// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});
```

So when we click on any item, the menu is closed. You can do this to prevent the menu from closing when you click on a dropdown menu.

```
// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.navbar-collapse ul li:not(.dropdown) a').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Now I just have to change the text-color so it can be seen on the background and I'll be good to go-- how can this be done without also changing the text color for desktop view?

Comment: I see you change the color with `<font color="#080A21">FAQ</font>`. You souldn't. It's better to use CSS. You should do something like this with CSS :

`@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-collapse ul li .dropdown a {
        color: #080A21;
    }
}`

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

so dropdown Opened but Same time Closing beCaUse inside Link have href="#"  delete dropdown Child a elements href attribute